# ORACLE => Oracle AQ

Tags: oracle, queue

what is the best practicies to remain in listen (with dequeue procedure) of a single queue with only a producer and only cosumer?
Is the DBMS_SCHEDULER the best solution?

Thanks, Best Regards.
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0):

you can create a trigger "ON DATABASE startup". In this trigger you can spawn a job, which will keep consuming AQ messages in a infinite loop.

ps: also it is good approach no to wait in dequeue forever. use wait parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but create a trigger at the DB level seems to me excessive. 
I'm evaluating usage of LISTEN o CALLBACK procedure to notify the enqueue.